# Windows Azure Mobile Services Push Notifications with .Net App and Html/JavaScript

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I can not find any examples using Windows Azure Mobile services that create the push notification itself in a c# server based app, and the notification itself is serviced in a browser based JavaScript client app (like AngularJS).

I thought there use to be a sample in the azure portal of this scenario but the only sample I see now is simply todo list item table insertion.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to send push notifications to a browser through Azure Notification Hubs, since push is done through a platform notification service. It might be possible to get notifications with Safari and Chrome since they are a similar format to iOS and Android notifications, but this is not officially supported.

Comment: pusher.com does it as well as sencha has an implementation they wrote themselves that programs websockets directly.  I'm looking for a way to do with Azure Mobile Services similar to Sencha.  Their solution is very much integrated into their library.

Comment: Also, I did test my app that uses angularjs and pusher on IE10 on my windows 8 and it works there also so I'm confused about the "not possible" comment above.  Could you address that please lindydonna

Comment: I would have thought SignalR would be what you want in this instance.  Is there a particular reason to use notifications?

Comment: It's basically a chat app in JavaScript.  I've not used signalR but my understanding was there is not a complete JavaScript implementation.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client